# Understanding topological modular forms

Tags: differential-topology

I am asking for good references to understanding topological modular forms.

Please don't laugh.

I am more or less an analyst and differential geometer, and I do know some algebraic topology and very little algebraic geometry. Most stuff I could find on the internet is way too heavy for me. Is there a really low-brow approach for people like me?

For example I found this on the web: http://math.berkeley.edu/~aaron/writing/ustars-tmf-beamer.pdf, "You could've invented tmf", and I did unerstand most of the first halft, but basically from the paragraph "Towards tmf", I am lost.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "understanding"?

Comment: Well, first knowing a definition. Then probably how to compute stuff in tmf (like tmf(some manifold)). In particular to understand what the Witten genus is.